# tx_news with pw_comment plugin typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, tx-news

I need to build a news detail page with comment option. When go to the detail page there must be an option for comment. So I configure pw_comment plugin. It's working fine. But all comments shows with every news. How can I show only comments with associated news? Please help me

My typoscript settings is

```
plugin.tx_pwcomments {
    settings {
        useEntryUid = 1
        entryUid = TEXT
        moderateNewComments = 0
        secondsBetweenTwoComments = 60
        entryUid.data = GP:tx_news|uid
        replaceUsernameWith = COA_INT
        replaceUsernameWith {
            10 = TEXT
            10.data = LLL:EXT:pw_comments/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:tx_pwcomments.newComment.loggedInAs

            20 = TEXT
            20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
            20.noTrimWrap = | <b>|</b>|

            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="loggedInAs">|</div>
        }

        replaceMailWith = TEXT
        replaceMailWith.stdWrap.char = 0
    }
}
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

My template includes the following coe

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 'NewsCommentLayout' ">
        <f:then>
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pwCommentsIndex" />
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pwCommentsNew"/>
        </f:then>

</f:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem.I edited the typoscript.

```
plugin.tx_pwcomments {
    settings {
        moderateNewComments = 0
        secondsBetweenTwoComments = 60
        enableCommentVotes = 0
        enableVoting = 0
        hideVoteButtons = 1
        replaceUsernameWith = COA_INT
        replaceUsernameWith {
            10 = TEXT
            10.data = LLL:EXT:pw_comments/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xml:tx_pwcomments.newComment.loggedInAs

            20 = TEXT
            20.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
            20.noTrimWrap = | <b>|</b>|

            stdWrap.wrap = <div class="loggedInAs">|</div>
        }

        replaceMailWith = TEXT
        replaceMailWith.stdWrap.char = 0
    }
}
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0

[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
plugin.tx_pwcomments.settings {
  useEntryUid = 1
  entryUid = TEXT
  entryUid.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
}
[global]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a condition somewhere to show only related comments per news not to all news systems.

Best would be do show them with TypoScript and then make a condition for certain news not to show up.